# Using "wouldn’t" instead of just "didn't"

Tags: modal-verbs

I’m really confused with using the word *would* sometimes. Such as this example:

> We didn’t get the polling research because apparently when the delivery came someone wouldn’t sign for it.

Why *wouldn't sign* is used instead of *didn't sign*. Is it because *apparently* was used and it seemed like a speaker wasn’t sure about things happened this way?

Answer (score 3):

We use "apparently" when we have been told something about which we cannot be certain. We can use 'would' to signify willingness in the past. "Apparently someone would not/wouldn't sign for it" means that the speaker has been told, but is not certain, that someone was present when the delivery came, but refused to sign for it.

> would modal verb (WILLINGNESS) ​ B1 past simple of will modal verb :
>   used to talk about what someone was willing to do or what something
>   was able to do:
>
> The car wouldn't start this morning.

[Apparently](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/apparently)

[Would](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/would)

Answer (score -2):

There's a slight difference in meaning.

Suppose that on Monday, the courier brought the polling data to an address but found nobody there. The rules require him to collect a signature before leaving the polling data. So because nobody signed for the data, the courier retained the polling data and you did not get it. You would say that you didn’t get the polling research because **nobody could sign for it**, or **nobody signed for it**.

But if the courier found a secretary at the desk and asked her to sign, and she refused, and he then found a second secretary and he also refused, so the courier retained the polling data and you did not get it, you would say that you didn’t get the polling research because **nobody would sign for it**.

The use of "would" makes us think about willingness and refusal, rather than just the fact that nobody signed. And the word "could" makes us think of ability.

Comment: There's a big difference in meaning between "somebody wouldn't sign for it" and "somebody didn't sign for it" (which nobody would say).

Comment: @Michael Harvey I also didn't say "somebody didn't sign for it," and I don't understand why you're bringing this distinction to my attention.

Comment: The OP asked why "wouldn't sign" was used instead of "didn't sign". You said there was a "slight" difference in meaning. I contend that the difference is more than slight. You introduced inverted formulations involving "nobody" and proceeded to answer as if these were the subject of the question. The remark about "somebody didn't sign" was addressed to the OP's question.